# how to do google finance 1 minute data bar?

Tags: google-sheets

Can you explain me how to do google finance 1 minute data bar ?

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA", "ALL", HOUR("16:00:00"), HOUR("23:00:00"), MINUTE())
```

what i need to fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no such thing. you can either have `DAILY` or `WEEKLY`

[image]

Comment: ok thanks, do you know where I can do that ?

Comment: [Here is the documentation for the GOOGLEFINANCE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en)